# Resources on which sites are fake news providers

Tags: discussion

Are there any resources on which websites are generators of fake news?

In this context, I mean sites which are scammers with a purely financial motive, not websites that have strongly held ideological agendas with a weak connection with reality.

Comment: A significant portion of fake news articles are funded by Kremlin and Pentagon. They popup out of nowhere.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin - actually, a significant portion are probably funded by ad click revenue :)   As P.T. Barnum never said, "there's a sucker born every minute"

Comment: @Mohammad They also sell foil hats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fake_news_websites#List_of_fake_news_sites lists some.